# how to use php to replace certain content within a table tag

Tags: php

I have thousands of html pages which contains below table content ~

```
<table height="94" cellpadding="0" width="760" border="0" cellspacing="0">
..... 
</table>
```

I want to delete this table tag:~

```
<table height="94" cellpadding="0" width="760" border="0" cellspacing="0">
```

and the content within it.

I tried:~

```
preg_replace("/<(\/?table height="/94/".*?)>/si","",$str);
```

but failed，it just removed all of my  tags and their content.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_replace('#<table height="94".*?>.*?</table>#si',"",$str);
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help! You can now accept that answer for me :)